# Can I set an HTML file as desktop background in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

Back in Windows XP you could use Active Desktop to set an HTML file as the wallpaper, is it possible to do this in Windows 7?

Comment: a live-page (aka "updates regularly") or just the static look of a page as it is right now?

Comment: i would like to make marquee text on my desktop.

Answer (score 6):

No you can't, Microsoft ripped that option out of Windows Vista and Windows 7.