# How can I set the live video feed from the ISS as my desktop background?

Tags: desktop-customization

NASA have recently started doing a live broadcast of the view from the ISS (if it's black, the ISS is over the night side of the Earth). http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/

How can I set this broadcast (or better, somehow obtain a periodic screen-cap of the feed) to become my desktop background? So that everyone benefits, solutions for Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows are desired.

Comment: relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/341155/can-i-set-an-html-file-as-desktop-background-in-windows-7?rq=1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

VLC has a [wallpaper mode](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Video#DirectX_Wallpaper) that allows to set any media it's currently playing as a wallpaper - the documentation mentions "DirectX" but I'm pretty sure that option exists on all platforms.

Now you need a way to open the stream directly inside VLC, unfortunately nothing is that easy and every streaming platform will do whatever they can to use their awful Flash-based solution.

However, they also need to provide streams for mobile devices that don't support Flash, and here's what this undocumented URL is for : http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8.

Once you have the URL, you just need to put the VLC command line (with the wallpaper option) inside a shortcut in the Startup folder of your start menu.

Here's a preliminary command line I came up with, however it has several issues like not being fullscreen, so you'll have to tinker with the `--zoom` parameter (`--width` and `--height` have no effect unfortunately).

```
vlc --video-wallpaper --zoom 2 --no-osd --qt-start-minimized --qt-notification 0 --qt-system-tray http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8
```

Open your `Startup` folder, you can just use copy/paste this path directly in your start menu to open it : `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Create a new shortcut in that folder, it should point to `vlc.exe`, the path itself should be quoted and the options should be appended after the quoted path, like this :

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --video-wallpaper --zoom 2 --no-osd --qt-start-minimized --qt-notification 0 --qt-system-tray http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8
```

Finally you can test your changes by clicking on the new entry you just created in your start menu (it's in the `Startup` folder), or log out and log back in.

Note that you have to enable display of the desktop icons, otherwise it won't work, not sure why.

Comment: eh this doesn't work that great, i wonder if there are other solutions

Comment: @Sickest yeah it's not very good but it's the most efficient solution, way more efficient than running software that displays a web page (with the Flash plugin) as a wallpaper. The best would still be to have a script that only takes a screenshot of the stream every X minutes and sets it as a wallpaper.

Comment: @André Do you know of a solution for Mac 10.6.8? I want the same URL but can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: Could you expand a bit on "enable display of the desktop icons"? I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @TomHart Windows allows you to hide the desktop icons by right-clicking on the desktop and unchecking "Display > Display desktop items", you need to make sure it's checked.

Comment: For osx: vlc --video-wallpaper --zoom 2 --no-osd  http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/17074538/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8
Vlc can be installed as a cask via homebrew

Answer (score 7):

There's an [easier way](http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/130551-set-windows-screen-saver-as-iss-live-stream/) that I found that involves downloading a [screensaver](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/djmclean/htmlscreensaver.html) that allows you to set html pages as your screensaver.

To get the feed to fill your entire screen, use the link for the pop-out rather than the channel. So for the ISS stream, you'd want to use:

> http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream/pop-out

This method worked perfectly for me and required little set up.

EDIT: Just now realized he was looking for a solution to set it to the background, not a screensaver. However, I'll leave this up as it is extremely relevant.

Edit 2: [Archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180722224238/http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/djmclean/htmlscreensaver.html) since the website is now down.

Edit 3: [HD feed](https://www.ustream.tv/embed/17074538?autoplay=true&volume=0&controls=false&showtile=false&forced-quality=high)

Comment: This may be useful, but it isn't an answer to the question (so it may get modded down / deleted). Here is an idea: ask a new question on how to set the ISS video stream as a screensaver, and then answer it yourself with this same answer. Then delete this answer from this question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way around using livestreamer. Se also this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/849095/508131).

### First step : installing livestreamer.

[Install livestreamer](https://livestreamer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)

### Simple HD stream with VLC :

This command displays [High Definition Earth-Viewing System (HDEV)](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/) on full screen on wallpaper mode.

```
livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
```

### HD stream with Audio (crew/control conversations)

This displays the [High Definition Earth-Viewing System (HDEV)](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/) and add sound from another stream, [Live ISS](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream), 
accompanied by audio of conversations between the crew and Mission Control.

```
livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/9408562?html5ui best --player "cvlc --no-video" & livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
```

### Bash ON/ OFF script (tested on Ubuntu)

```
#!/bin/bash
PS=`ps -ef`
if echo "$PS"|grep -q 'vlc -I dummy';
    then echo "off";
    kill $(ps aux | grep 'vlc -I dummy' | awk '{print $2}')
else echo "on";
    livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/9408562?html5ui best --player "cvlc --no-video" & livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
fi
```

### Improved bash script (Ubuntu specific)

(just select the path of a icon you want to be displayed with notifications, or delete the "Icon=" third line and both "-i $Icon" options)

```
#!/bin/bash
PS=`ps -ef`
Icon="/path/to/nasa_icon.png"

if echo "$PS"|grep -q 'vlc -I dummy';
    then notify-send -i $Icon "  ISS background OFF" \ "\"Houston, We've Got a Problem !\"";
    kill $(ps aux | grep 'vlc -I dummy' | awk '{print $2}')
else notify-send -i $Icon " ISS background ON" \ "Dowloading data from ISS...";
    livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/9408562?html5ui best --player "cvlc --no-video" & livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
fi
```

Comment: Very good suggestion, works like a charm, but do you have any idea how to make this work on dual monitors?

Comment: It works fine for me with dual monitors. What do you want exactly ? Same video on both ? Different stream on each ?

Comment: Extend the stream on both both monitors. Just like you would watch a movie on 2 monitors, half on the left and half on the right.

Comment: Sorry, never done that, but I guess you can find what you're looking for [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help). Take a look at `--video-splitter` option.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

This guy made a System Preferences extension for the Mac. Works on Mac OS X Yosemite... not sure how far back the compatibility goes.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsobolev.us%2Fiss-hd-earth-viewing-experiment-screen-saver%2F&ei=BapCVKalIKX1iQKr0YH4BA&usg=AFQjCNFy587sR98w-D5SPXtgUwJrqH8tNA&sig2=_nlyDfljiKYKE72ry_ZxIg

Answer (score 1):

You can try [livestreamer](https://livestreamer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  I had to do a bit of work to get Python libraries installed to be able to view the higher def stream on Ubuntu.  There are prepackaged Windows binaries that might not have that problem, I haven't tried them.

I'm using it right now to watch the ISS feed directly in VLC at 720p.  The command is

```
livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload 720p+ --player vlc
```

Finally, use VLC's wallpaper mode as explained in André's post.

Thanks to [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/watch-live-video-of-earth-on-your-raspberry-pi) about streaming the ISS feed on the Raspberry Pi, which pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC, you can choose to align the video to the left, centre or the right.  In addition, set the ratio of the display you want the feed to be placed on in the Aspect Ratio or Crop settings.  I have it playing perfectly in full screen on my left monitor of a dual head setup.

Also, you can open the playlist file mentioned above and edit it to only have the 480 feed within it.  This can be done in Wordpad or a competent text editor.  Notepad will corrupt it, since the linefeeds are not completely windows-compatible.

Your `playlist.m3u8` file should look as follows:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1194092,CODECS="avc1.77.31",RESOLUTION=854x480
http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/watch/playlist.m3u8?cid=17074538&stream=live_6&appType=103&appVersion=3&conn=wifi&group=iphone
```

To make the video display only on one screen, go to **VLC settings**, then go to the **Show Settings** box at the bottom and choose **All**.

Next, go to the **Video** section in the left tree, near the bottom, and click on it.  In the right pane that appears, scroll down to the bottom of the Video settings and, in the **Video alignment** section, select **Left**, **Center** or **Right**, depending on your preference.  Left will align to your left screen.  Center will display the video across both displays with black bars on either side, and Right will align to your right display.

Finally, switch back to Simple settings, then under Video make sure your Output drop-down in the Display section is set to Automatic.

Close the settings for now.  Next, in the main VLC window, go to the Crop settings and choose the correct ratio for the display you are using.  In my case, the ratio is 16:10.

This will both align and crop the video to a single display only.  Perfect!  The crop is important so the VLC viewport doesn't spill onto the other display.  Try experimenting with it until you get the desired effect.

**Update:** Maybe I was incorrect about the display switch.  I can't get it to show on my right display!  Any ideas?  It still sits perfectly on my left screen though.  Aspect ratio seems to be a better idea so it doesn't chop off the video, even though it smooshes it a little bit as the feed is wider.

If anyone has suggestions on how to create a desktop shortcut for this, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, you could use my [`Plash`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Plash) app. Just enter the video URL in the app and it will set as your desktop background.